# Vue.js 2 bootstrap-vue popover persistence issue with popper.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-4, popover, popper.js

I'm trying to implement (without any 3rd party libraries) a popover on a button which persists when the mouse is hovered into the popover itself.

The reason for this is that I want to place a call to action button within the popover, and thus need to persist.

I can't find any option to do this within popper.js configuration (or maybe I've overlooked it), as I went as far as implementing this previously with a jQuery workaround with utilised .on methods which forced the popover not to hide.

Has anyone got any examples or suggestions on how to do this without resorting to jQuery? Willing to consider other 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Vue Popper - https://github.com/RobinCK/vue-popper. It does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

or try this one, with popper v2 https://www.npmjs.com/package/@soldeplata/popper-vue